# remove the black space surrounding the image using opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Good Day! I'm using imwrite command to save the image below after cropping them in OpenCV (C++)  but it seems like it included the black portion surrounding it in writing. All I want is to save the cropped one. Please help.

[image]

Here's my code

```
Mat mask,draft,res;
int nPixels;
char c=0;

while(true && c!='q') {
        imshow("SAMPLE", img);
        if(!roi.isSet())
            roi.set("SAMPLE");
        if (roi.isSet()) {
                roi.createMask(img.size());
                mask = roi.getMask();
                res = mask & img.clone();
                imwrite("masked.png",res);

                imshow("draft", res);


        }

        c = waitKey(1); 

    }
```

Comment: There is no image. Moreover, can you include the code that you use to crop and save the image? Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: need to see some code

Comment: Mat mask,draft,res;
 int nPixels;
 char c=0;

 while(true && c!='q') {
   imshow("SAMPLE", img);
   if(!roi.isSet())
    roi.set("SAMPLE");
   if (roi.isSet()) {
     roi.createMask(img.size());
     mask = roi.getMask();
     res = mask & img.clone();
     imwrite("masked.png",res);
 
     imshow("draft", res);

     
   }
   
   c = waitKey(1); 
  
  }

Comment: Edit your question and add the code. Its unreadable as a comment.

Comment: oh yes. thank you. first time here. :)

Comment: i want to save the image without the black background.

Comment: just create a cv::rect of the part you want to save and do `cv::Mat im = res(rect)` then save im :)

Comment: masking and cropping are very different things.

Comment: i mean from the cropped image, during saving it into a new image file, the black background is included. I wanted to remove that one and save only the cropped image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to crop an image and save the croped image (see comment from api55). Maybe that helps you.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("Path/To/Image/image.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
if(image.empty())
  return -1;

cv::Rect roi(0, 0, 100, 100); // define roi here as x0, y0, width, height
cv::Mat cropedImg(img, roi);

cv::imwrite("Path/To/Save/Location/cropedImage.png", cropedImg);
```